# Which database for survey app

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I need to build a very simple mobile survey app. The app will ask for different questions where people can give one of 3 possible answers, which will be always "yes", "no" or "maybe".

To save these questions and answers I need a simple scheme with 2 tables like:

- question(id:int, question:varchar, createdAt:timestamp)
- answer(id:int, questionId:int, answer:enum, createdAt:timestamp)

I'm asking myself if I should go for a good ol' MySql for that or if I should choose a NoSQL database like MongoDB.

I have following minimal requirements:

- Concurrent (non locking), fast inserts should be possible
- Fast read queries to do some analytics
- Indexing of table data
- Several millions of entries should be no problem (hard disk space is the limit :)
- Backups should easily be possible
- Convenient date/time functions

I think MySQL should do the trick, but I've never tried out databases like MongoDB before. The app will leverage JSON as data exchange format and I know that MongoDB plays quite well with that.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Best regards

Comment: Aha, don't really understand why this should be off-topic. Why should this question become "quickly obsolet"? Anyway, thanks for your answers Joshua & Jehad!

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL is often overlooked but might be worth your attention.  It supports MVCC for concurrency, can do analytic SQL queries easily, supports indexes, scales up well enough, can do hot backups, supports date functions, and even has JSON data types.  Binary JSON (aka: JSONB, BSON) is being added to newer versions, which will give you the ability to index on JSON content and have improved analytic function & performance.

Check this out article on Phoronix:

*Binary JSON Support Added To PostgreSQL, Competes With MongoDB*
http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTY0MTU

Answer (score 0):

For this application, and for the mentioned requirements, both MySQL and MongoDB are more than enough. However, I'd choose MySQL for the following reasons:

- MySQL is an RDBMS, which has more functionalities at the server's level
- MongoDB is good when the data module is inconsistent. i.e. when different 'rows' have different 'fields'
- MongoDB is scalable, but no need for scalability here.
- If you don't know any of them, I think MySQL is easier to start with.